# ZeroMQ cannot set ZMQ_RATE - Invalid Argument (using EPGM or PGM Multicast)

Tags: zeromq, multicast

I cannot set the max rate by **`ZMQ_RATE`** (which default at a very low 100 kbits/sec) on a `ZeroMQ` multicast socket - the call to `zmq_setsocketopt()` fails (using `C` langauge).

I need the rate much higher as my application involves streaming video.

Can anyone shine any light on this - here is the stripped down code to replicate the problem

```
void* _context;
void* _responder;

_context    = zmq_ctx_new ();
_responder  = zmq_socket ( _context, ZMQ_SUB );

int64_t val = 100000;
int rc;

rc          = zmq_setsockopt( _responder, ZMQ_RATE, &val, sizeof(int64_t) );
int ze2     = zmq_errno ();

int           major,  minor,  patch;
zmq_version( &major, &minor, &patch );

printf( "DIAG[zmq_setsockopt() API:%d.%d.%d] RC: (%d) ~ Errno: (%d) ~ Error:(%s)\n",
        major,
        minor,
        patch
        rc,
        ze2,
        zmq_strerror( ze2 )
        );
```

The output of the above is:

```
     DIAG[zmq_setsockopt() API:4.0.4] RC: (-1) ~ Errno: (22) ~ Error: (Invalid argument)
```

If I change a socket type to `ZMQ_PUB` I also get the error.
Have tested many rates from 1 to 100000 in various orders or magnitude, all fail the same way.

The version is 4.0.4 running on Windows 7

Comment: API version is important. It decides, whether all the traffic goes to every SUB-side, if still using versions, where ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE topic filter is processed on each SUB-receiving node ( keeping both the transport & processing overheads even in case none SUB has subscribed to any PUB topic ). You may somehow tweak this with carefull tuning the Context attributes & ioThread affinity mappings, but worth update if other design constraints permit. Your research in streaming apps seem to be processing intensive, so due IO-tuning for any distributed processing needs a lot of care.

Comment: Thanks I have editted based on below response - the version is 4.0.4.  I will upgrade ZeroMQ to the latest to see if this persists though in production everything is running 4.0.4 so I was reluctant to do so incase other issues arose anyway worth a go

Comment: Well, in some projects, I had to keep as old as ver 2.1.11 API compatibility because of missing newer language binding on some distributed systems nodes. 4.0.4 should not be an issue. ( + ref. update below )

Answer (score 0):

### **`API`** for `zmq_setsockopt()` has only these possible error-states:

> **`EINVAL`**
>   The requested option `option_name` is unknown, or the requested `option_len` or `option_value` is invalid.
>   **`ETERM`**
>   The ØMQ context associated with the specified socket was terminated.
>   **`ENOTSOCK`**
>   The provided socket was invalid.
>   **`EINTR`**
>   The operation was interrupted by delivery of a signal.

My suspect is the **`EINVAL`**
and a minimum step to forward the code closer towards a **`MCVE`**
 is to do this and post the terminal outputs:

```
void* _context;
void* _responder;

assert ( ZMQ_RATE == 8 );                           # mod.000: validate zmq.h compliance
assert ( ZMQ_SUB  == 2 );                           # mod.000: validate zmq.h compliance

_context    = zmq_ctx_new ();

assert ( _context );                                # mod.000: validate <context> instance

_responder  = zmq_socket ( _context, ZMQ_SUB );

assert ( _responder );                              # mod.000: validate <socket> instance

int val     = 123;                                  # mod.000: enforce (int)

int rc      = zmq_setsockopt( _responder, ZMQ_RATE, &val, sizeof(val) );
int ze2     = zmq_errno ();

int           major,  minor,  patch;
zmq_version( &major, &minor, &patch );

printf( "DIAG[zmq_setsockopt() API:%d.%d.%d] RC: (%d) ~ Errno: (%d) ~ Error: (%s)\n",
         major,
         minor,
         patch
         rc,
         ze2,
         zmq_strerror( ze2 )
         );
```

---

### `UPDATE 000.INF`:

> From `ZeroMQ` **`v3.x`**, filtering happens at the publisher side when using a connected protocol ( `tcp://` or `ipc://`). Using the **`epgm://`** protocol, filtering happens at the subscriber side.
> In **`ZeroMQ v2.x`**, all filtering happened at the subscriber side.

### `UPDATE 000.w7.CHECK`:

as per 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957547.aspx
 
may want to check REGISTRY for a {key: value}-presence/state of `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IGMPLevel`
<-- **not to be missing or `0`**
that is kind of a morbid part of an "answer", but **`w7`** could have multicast forbidden ( which should not self-demonstrate by `zmq_errno()` but it seems better to be sure of rather the solid grounds than building on moving sands, doesn't it? ).

---

### `UPDATE 001.w7.Final_step`:

**In case** the indicated **`EINVAL`** error gets returned also on a **`linux`**-based system, re-tested for the same scenario, [fill a **`ZeroMQ`**  BugReport](http://zeromq.org/docs:issue-tracking).

**Otherwise**, the trouble gets resolved to be **`w7`**-related, consult your localhost administrator for fixing the issue.

> The **`pgm`** transport implementation requires access to raw IP sockets. Additional privileges may be required on some operating systems for this operation. Applications not requiring direct interoperability with other PGM implementations are encouraged to use the **`epgm`** transport instead which does not require any special privileges.

Comment: Thanks for that - I will edit the question to incorporate.  The output is DIAG[zmq_setsockopt() API:4.0.4] RC: (-1) ~ Errno: (22) ~ Error: (Invalid argument)  so it is indeed EINVAL

Comment: While this might look obscure for a code-master, would you mind to use a damn hack for further explicit elimination of the root cause -- using explicit int type as per API doc in `int val = 123;rc = ... sizeof(val));` and `assert ( _responder ); assert ( ZMQ_RATE == 8 );` ?

Comment: Thanks for your subsequent edit 000.w7.CHECK.  I should clarify that I can communicate data over multicast between a pair of the w7 machines - but only at 100kbit/sec.  I am trying to PUB approx 5MByte/sec of JPEG data down the EPGM channel but profiling the network reveals data on the line at rate of 100kbit/sec.  The (slow) receipt of these packets at the SUBing machine indicates that multicast is working but is being throttled, which is why I am trying to change this socket option at both source and destination, as its default is conspicuously set at 100kbit/sec.

Comment: Thanks for your edit 000.INF - These assertions are a great idea for a check however they all pass as true, and even with the sizeof(val) substituted into the setsockopt I get the same failure result from 0MQ.  Also in my original post I was using a int64_t not an int as the option value - which is what the API docs request (this is a win32 project so an int on my platform is shorter) but in any case both types result in the same error.   This check was also performed on 4.0.4 windows 7.